# Markdown tabs in GitLab Markdown

Tags: gitlab, markdown, code-documentation

I am writing documentation that has steps for Windows, Mac, Linux.
I want to make it look like this HTML5 tabbed [HTML5 example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp) 
there is support for [HTML in gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#inline-html) markdown
There is a reference to a [sanitation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/html-pipeline/1.11.0/HTML/Pipeline/SanitizationFilter#WHITELIST-constant) class that validates the inline HTML in gitlab marrkdown

My question is:

- Recommendations to achieve the tabbed documentation. Is there a workaround for displaying CSS correctly in markdown?
- how to make this work?

Comment: This may be related: [Add tabbed code snippets in markdown](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/17381).

Answer (score 1):

Simply insert the relevant HTML/CSS/JS into your Markdown document.

As Markdown's [Syntax Rules](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) state (emphasis in original):

> Markdown's syntax is intended for one purpose: to be used as a format
>   for *writing* for the web.
>
> Markdown is not a replacement for HTML, or even close to it. Its
>   syntax is very small, corresponding only to a very small subset of
>   HTML tags. The idea is *not* to create a syntax that makes it easier
>   to insert HTML tags. In my opinion, HTML tags are already easy to
>   insert. The idea for Markdown is to make it easy to read, write, and
>   edit prose. HTML is a *publishing* format; Markdown is a *writing*
>   format. Thus, Markdown's formatting syntax only addresses issues that
>   can be conveyed in plain text.
>
> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown's syntax, you simply
>   use HTML itself. There's no need to preface it or delimit it to
>   indicate that you're switching from Markdown to HTML; you just use
>   the tags.
>
> The only restrictions are that block-level HTML elements -- e.g. `<div>`,
>   `<table>`, `<pre>`, `<p>`, etc. -- must be separated from surrounding
>   content by blank lines, and the start and end tags of the block should
>   not be indented with tabs or spaces. Markdown is smart enough not
>   to add extra (unwanted) `<p>` tags around HTML block-level tags.

However, there is one down side to this:

> Note that Markdown formatting syntax is not processed within block-level
>   HTML tags. E.g., you can't use Markdown-style `*emphasis*` inside an
>   HTML block.

Finally, there is the concern that you appear to looking to have this document hosted on a third party site (perhaps in a readme on Gitlab). Most third party sites who process and host Markdown documents (including Gitlab) run the output through an HTML sanitizer for security reasons (to avoid XSS attaches, etc). Therefore, you are likely to find that various required hooks in your HTML will be stripped out and it won't work. Of course, this won't be a problem on your own site where you have total control.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried and the html tabs are stripped off. Unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was tried in readme.rd from the text processor used by Microsoft VsCode and commited to gitlab. In the attached picture there is the rendering. It was not as expected. Perhaps the functionality to have tabs will be available soon.

[image: Gitlab render of the tab html]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is "collapsible sections" in GitLab Flavored Markdown. Link to documentation: [link](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#collapsible-section)